# How to use vlookup or indirect to copy data from another sheet, without changing the value on update of database

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

So I've set up automatic MySQL sheet that gets the data from it every day at 8pm.

I've set up everything with vlookup, and tried indirect. But I can't figure out how to make sure the values don't change when the data from database updates.

Does anyone know how to make it so that Vlookup or indirect doesn't change the value when database updates the numbers?

Comment: What do you me mean by " automatic MySQL sheet"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid that a spreadsheet function like VLOOKUP and INDIRECT don't change. The alternative is to replace the cell formula by it's result.

You could do this manually by using copy then paste only values, by using Google Apps Script of the Sheets REST API.